# Python: How to find the maximum number in a list using the for loop, but the list is through user input

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

Assignment question:
Write a function called list_max that takes a list named a as input and finds and returns its largest element. Don't use the built-in max function.

The function is written like this to start:

```py
def list_max(a):
      # What I have so far is:
      for num in a:
        if num > a:
         return num
```

But this is returning back to me as incorrect. Is there something I am missing or not doing?

Comment: read thru the list, keep track of the highest seen at each point

Comment: Did you run the code? What is the result (or error message)?

Comment: `if num > a:` is trying to compare a number with a list. You should be saving a `max` value somewhere and then comparing `num` to that.